# MySQL performance issue on multiple select inside each other

Tags: mysql, optimization

Below you can see my query is a big query running over a big table if you consider 200,000 data big but it loads over 10 sec to load I want to get expert help to optimize the query: any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT    mt5_users.Name       AS Name, 
      Test2.Login AS SLogin, 
      ( 
             SELECT COUNT(Test.Order) 
             FROM   ( 
                           SELECT * 
                           FROM   ( 
                                           SELECT   MAX(`Order`)                                                                                 AS `Order`,
                                                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Time SEPARATOR ","), ",", 1), ",", -1) AS OPEN_TIME,
                                                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Time SEPARATOR ","), ",", 2), ",", -1) AS CLOSE_TIME,
                                                    MAX(Profit)                                                                                  AS Profit,
                                                    MAX(Storage)                                                                                 AS Storage,
                                                    MAX(Login)                                                                                   AS Login,
                                                    MAX(Action)                                                                                  AS Action,
                                                    MAX(Entry)                                                                                   AS Entry
                                           FROM     `mt5_deals_2020` 
                                           WHERE    Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND      "2020-10-01" 
                                           AND      Entry IN ("0", 
                                                              "1") 
                                           GROUP BY PositionID) AS Main 
                           WHERE  OPEN_TIME != CLOSE_TIME) As Test
             WHERE  Login = SLogin 
             AND    Test.Entry <> "0" 
             AND    Test.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND    "2020-10-01" 
             AND    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Test.OPEN_TIME,Test.CLOSE_TIME) <= "5"
             AND    Test.Action <= 1 )        AS Scalp, 
      SUM(Test2.Profit+Test2.Storage) AS Profit, 
      ( 
             SELECT COUNT(mt5_deals_2020.order) 
             FROM   mt5_deals_2020 
             WHERE  Login = SLogin 
             AND    mt5_deals_2020.Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND    "2020-10-01" 
             AND    mt5_deals_2020.Action <= 1 
             AND    mt5_deals_2020.Entry <> "0" ) AS Trades, 
      ( 
             SELECT SUM(mt5_deals_2020.Profit+mt5_deals_2020.Storage) 
             FROM   mt5_deals_2020 
             WHERE  Login = SLogin 
             AND    mt5_deals_2020.Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND    "2020-10-01" 
             AND    mt5_deals_2020.Entry <> "0" 
             AND    mt5_deals_2020.Action <= 1 ) AS PL 
FROM      ( 
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM   ( 
                                 SELECT   MAX(`Order`)                                                                                 AS `Order`,
                                          SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Time SEPARATOR ","), ",", 1), ",", -1) AS OPEN_TIME,
                                          SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Time SEPARATOR ","), ",", 2), ",", -1) AS CLOSE_TIME,
                                          MAX(Profit)                                                                                  AS Profit,
                                          MAX(Storage)                                                                                 AS Storage,
                                          MAX(Login)                                                                                   AS Login,
                                          MAX(Action)                                                                                  AS Action,
                                          MAX(Entry)                                                                                   AS Entry
                                 FROM     `mt5_deals_2020` 
                                 WHERE    Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND      "2020-10-01" 
                                 AND      Entry IN ("0", 
                                                    "1") 
                                 GROUP BY PositionID) AS Main1
                 WHERE  OPEN_TIME != CLOSE_TIME) As Test2
LEFT JOIN mt5_users 
ON        Test2.Login = mt5_users.Login 
WHERE     mt5_users.Group IN ("KUVVARSTUSD", 
                              "real\\KUV3VARSIUSD", 
                              "real\\KUVVARPLUSD", 
                              "real\\KUVVARGOUSD", 
                              "real\\KUVVARGOEUR" 
                              ) 
AND       Test2.CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND       "2020-10-01" 
AND       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Test2.OPEN_TIME,Test2.CLOSE_TIME) <= "5" 
AND       Test2.Action <= 1 
GROUP BY  Test2.Login
```

I need the time difference of an opening and closing order with some other data so on inside selects what I do is just that.

Explain result added:
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the query? An explanation of the logic, along with sample data and results, would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify

```
        SELECT  COUNT(Test.Order)
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  *
                    FROM  
                    (
                        SELECT  ...
                            FROM  `mt5_deals_2020`
                            WHERE  Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND "2020-10-01"
                              AND  Entry IN ("0", "1")
                            GROUP BY  PositionID
                    ) AS Main
                    WHERE  OPEN_TIME != CLOSE_TIME
            ) As Test
            WHERE  Login = SLogin
              AND  Test.Entry <> "0"
              AND  ...
```

to

```
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM  
                    (
                        SELECT  ...
                            FROM  `mt5_deals_2020`
                            WHERE  Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND "2020-10-01"
                              AND  Entry IN ("0", "1")
                            GROUP BY  PositionID
                    ) AS Main
                    WHERE  OPEN_TIME != CLOSE_TIME
                    HAVING  Login = SLogin
                       AND  Test.Entry <> "0"
                       AND  ...
```

Notes:

- `COUNT(x)` tests `x` for being `NOT NULL`; I suspect that is irrelevant.
- `HAVING` is like `WHERE` but it can reference expressions, such as aggregates like `SUM()`.
- Your formulation has a `SELECT *`, which involves creating a big(?) temp table with all the 'columns'.  Mine avoids that.

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` is messy.  Consider redesigning the schema so that you don't need to use it.

What are the possible values of `Entry` and `Action`?  There may be a better way to do the tests on those.  For example if `Entry` can be only 0 or 1, it is better to say `mt5_deals_2020.Entry = 1`, thereby opening the door for an index.

Potential bug:

```
Time BETWEEN "2020-09-01" AND "2020-10-01"
```

If `Time` is a `DATE`, then that includes the first of October.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  I prefer the following:

```
    Time >= "2020-09-01"
AND Time  < "2020-09-01" + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

`mt5_users` might benefit from this composite, covering, index:

```
INDEX(Login, Group, Name)   -- in this order
```

After doing some of those, come back for more discussion if you like.